# Unable to open pyspark on HDInsight and ADLS Gen 2 with Storage Account Contributor permissions

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I'm seeing the following error when running pyspark command to open spark session in HDInsight 4.0 connected to ADLS Gen 2 (Hierarchical NS)

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, PUT, https://<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<cluster>/user/<username>/.sparkStaging/application_1584094668947_0135?action=setAccessControl&timeout=90, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

My user has "Storage Blob Contributor" permissions enabled.  This command works when using "Storage Blob Owner" Role however I want to avoid granting that level to all of our developers.  Is there a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior.  You may check out my [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c8d58a4-04d1-4d0a-a9fa-c48c9991f1ab/azure-databricks-throwing-403-error?forum=AzureDatabricks) thread, which addressing the same issue.

**Note:** When performing the steps in the Assign the application to a role, make sure to assign the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to the service principal.

Only roles explicitly defined for data access permit a security principal to access blob or queue data. Roles such as **Owner**, **Contributor**, and **Storage Account Contributor** permit a security principal to **manage a storage account**, **but do not provide access to the blob or queue data within that account.**

Access to blob or queue data in the Azure portal can be authorized using either your Azure AD account or the storage account access key. For more information, see Use the Azure portal to access blob or queue data.

To understand more in detail, you may go to Storage Account => Access Control (IAM) => Roles => Click on (…)  => Permissions
[image]

**Checkout permissions for Owner**:

[image]

**Checkout permissions for Storage Blob Data Contributor:**

[image]